# How do I display a form data containing first name last name email and password validations in the same page using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function validateform() {
var status = true;
var f = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"];
var l = document.forms["myForm"]["lname"];
var a = document.forms["myForm"]["age"];
var g = document.forms["myForm"]["gender"];
var m = document.forms["myForm"]["mobile"];
var u = document.forms["myForm"]["uname"];

if (f.value == "") {
document.getElementById("fname-error").innerHTML = "Please Enter your First
Name";
document.getElementById("fname-error").style.color = "Red";
status = false;
} else {
document.getElementById("fname-error").innerHTML = "Valid First Name";
document.getElementById("fname-error").style.color = "Green";
status = true;
}
if (l.value == "") {
document.getElementById("lname-error").innerHTML = "Please Enter your Last 
Name";
document.getElementById("lname-error").style.color = "Red";
status = false;
} else {
document.getElementById("lname-error").innerHTML = "Valid Last Name";
document.getElementById("lname-error").style.color = "Green";
status = true;
}
if (a.value == "") {
document.getElementById("age-error").innerHTML = "Please Enter your age";
document.getElementById("age-error").style.color = "Red";
status = false;
} else {
document.getElementById("age-error").innerHTML = "Age Selected";
document.getElementById("age-error").style.color = "Green";
status = true;
}
if (g.value == "") {
document.getElementById("gender-error").innerHTML = "Please select your 
gender";
document.getElementById("gender-error").style.color = "Red";
status = false;
} else {
document.getElementById("gender-error").innerHTML = "Gender Selected";
document.getElementById("gender-error").style.color = "Green";
status = true;
}
if (m.value.length < 10 || m.value.length > 10) {
document.getElementById("mobile-error").innerHTML = "Please Enter a valid 
Mobile Number";
document.getElementById("mobile-error").style.color = "Red";
status = false;
} else {
document.getElementById("mobile-error").innerHTML = "Valid Mobile Number";
document.getElementById("mobile-error").style.color = "Green";
status = true;
}
if (u.value == "") {
document.getElementById("uname-error").innerHTML = "Please Choose a 
Username";
document.getElementById("uname-error").style.color = "Red";
status = false;
} else {
document.getElementById("uname-error").innerHTML = "Valid Username";
document.getElementById("uname-error").style.color = "Green";
status = true;
}
return true;
}

function checkPass(passId) {
if (/^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]{6,16}$/.test(passId)) {
document.getElementById("pass1-error").innerHTML = "You have entered valid 
Password.";
document.getElementById("pass1-error").style.color = "Green";
return true;
}
return false;
}

function ValidatePassid() {
var passID = document.forms["myForm"]["passid1"];

if ((passID.value == null) || (passID.value == "")) {
document.getElementById("pass1-error").innerHTML = "Please Enter your 
password";
document.getElementById("pass1-error").style.color = "Red";
passID.focus();
return false;
}

if (checkPass(passID.value) == false) {
passID.value = "";
document.getElementById("pass1-error").innerHTML = "Invalid Password";
document.getElementById("pass1-error").style.color = "Red";
passID.focus();
return false;
}
return true;
}
function Validate() {
    var pass1 = document.forms["myForm"]["passid1"];
    var pass2 = document.forms["myForm"]["passid2"];

    if (pass1.value != pass2.value) {
        document.getElementById("pass2-error").innerHTML = "Passwords do not 
 match.";
        document.getElementById("pass2-error").style.color = "Red";
        return false;
    } else {
    document.getElementById("pass2-error").innerHTML = "Passwords match.";
    document.getElementById("pass2-error").style.color = "Green";
    return true;
    }
    return true;
}

function checkEmail(emailId) {
if (/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(emailId)) {
document.getElementById("email-error").innerHTML = ("You have entered a 
valid email");
document.getElementById("email-error").style.color = "Green";
return true;
}
return false;
}

function ValidateEmail() {
var emailID = document.forms["myForm"]["email"];

if ((emailID.value == null) || (emailID.value == "")) {
document.getElementById("email-error").innerHTML = "Please Enter your Email 
ID";
document.getElementById("email-error").style.color = "Red";
emailID.focus();
return false;
}
if (checkEmail(emailID.value) == false) {
emailID.value = "";
document.getElementById("email-error").innerHTML = "Invalid Email Adderess";
document.getElementById("email-error").style.color = "Red";
emailID.focus();
return false;
}
return true;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form name="myForm" id="MyForm">
<fieldset>
  <legend>
    <h4>Registration Form</h4>
  </legend>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>First Name:</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="fname" />
        <div id="fname-error" class="error"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Last Name:</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="lname" />
        <div id="lname-error" class="error"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Age:</td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" name="age" minlength ="0" maxlength = "100"/>
        <div id="age-error" class="error"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gender:</td>
      <td>
        <input list="genders" name="gender" />
        <datalist id="genders">
          <option value="Male">
            <option value="Female">
              <option value="Other">
        </datalist>

        <div id="gender-error" class="error"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Mobile:</td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" name="mobile" minlength="10" maxlength ="10"/>
        <div id="mobile-error" class="error"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Username:</td>
      <td>
        <input type="userid" name="uname" />
        <div id="uname-error" class="error"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Password:</td>
      <td>
        <input type="password" name="passid1" minlength="6" />
        <div id="pass1-error" class="error"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>Confirm Password:</td>
    <td>
    <input type="password" name="passid2" minlength="6"/>
    <div id="pass2-error" class="error"></div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>E-mail:</td>
      <td>
        <input type="email" name="email" />
        <div id="email-error" class="error"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <button onlick="return !!(validateform() & ValidatePassid() & 
 Validate() & ValidateEmail())">Submit</button>
        <span id="display">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </fieldset>
  </form>
  </body>
  </html>
```

I should not use any server side languages since it is a school project, I tried to display the data using onclick but it is not working. Can any one solve this problem and guide me through it. Even if you suggest to use any server side languages I can't use them, because they didn't teach those. Only basic JavaScript can be used to dispaly the form values.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery validation js...the prior reason for suggesting you is that you don't have to do manual code as that js will automatically track this.

https://jqueryvalidation.org/

Hope, this will help you.

Comment: i can't use jquery. Just the basic java script